# Download JSON data and convert it to CSV using Python

Tags: python, json, csv, yahoo-pipes

I'm currently using Yahoo Pipes which provides me with a JSON file from an URL.

I would like to be able to fetch it and convert it into a CSV file, and I have no idea where to begin (I'm a complete beginner in Python).

How can I fetch the JSON data from the URL?
How can I transform it to CSV?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example json and csv snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import urllib2
import json
import csv

def getRows(data):
    # ?? this totally depends on what's in your data
    return []

url = "http://www.yahoo.com/something"
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
data = json.loads(data)

fname = "mydata.csv"
with open(fname,'wb') as outf:
    outcsv = csv.writer(outf)
    outcsv.writerows(getRows(data))
```

Comment: SO should have some rubber-stamp comment buttons. One such: """Python 2.x: Always open csv files in binary mode."

Comment: @John Machin: please correct me if wrong - my understanding was that csv files had to be read as binary but written as text?

Comment: @John Machin: ok, tested it; yes, writing as text results in extra row breaks. Come to think of it, I do vaguely remember that.